# Regex for validating barcodes

Tags: python, regex

Im new to regexes. Im having a hard time understanding everything and I wanted to write a not so simple program about e-mails but then decided on barcodes. The barcode is valid if it:

1. Is surrounded with a "@" followed by one or more "#"
2. Is at least 6  characters long (without the surrounding "@" or "#")
3. Starts with a capital letter
4. Contains only letters (lower and upper case) and digits
5. Ends with a capital letter

I tried a couple of things and achieved absolutely nothing. I even watched a detailed explanation of regexes but still can't come up with anything.

Sample input: @#GoodCodE@# would be valid but @Invalid_CodE@ / @#InvalidTry@# would not.

(@#+)([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{4,}[A-Z])(?:@#+) Thank you for all the help! ?= didn't include the @#+ so I replaced it with ?: which does apparently.

Comment: It would help if you add a sample input and expected output..much more easier to follow for some

Comment: ^ would also help to add your own attempt, no matter how terrible =). Without any sample data it look like you want to get capture group one of something like: `(@#+)([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{4,}[A-Z])(?=@#+)` (without leading/trailing @# combination)

Comment: (@#+)([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{4,}[A-Z])(@#+) worked. ?= excludes @#+ from the capture right? ?: also works so I assume it includes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following expression: `^@#+[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{4,}[A-Z]@#+$`

Broken down it means:

- `^` requires beginning of string (line)
- `@` match a @ character
- `#+` match one or more of # characters
- `[A-Z]` match an uppercase letter  (counts as 1st of the 6)
- `@[A-Za-z0-9]{4,}` match 4 or more of upper/lowercase letters and digits
- `[A-Z]` match an uppercase letter  (counts as last of the 6)
- `@` match a @ character
- `#+` match one or more of # characters
- `$` requires end of string (line)

Comment: That's right, but we need `(#)+` to get "one or more "#"".

Comment: Reading the OP's example data, I think the pattern is missing the `#` at the beginning. I think it should be like `^@#+[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{4,}[A-Z]@#+$` https://regex101.com/r/GZkDJH/1

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```py
import re


def check_re(inval):
    """
    >>> check_re('@#GoodCodE@#')
    True
    >>> check_re('@Invalid_CodE@/@#InvalidTry@#')
    False
    >>> check_re('@#IdE@#')
    False
    """
    bar_re = re.compile(r'^@#+[A-Z]([A-Za-z0-9]){4,}[A-Z]@#+$')
    m = re.match(bar_re, inval)
    return m is not None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

See the explanation in [Alain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61029360/8541499).